# Diferent values on x axis in SG Panel (SAS 9.4)

Tags: sas

I want to create a two-panel graph using proc sgpanel in SAS 9.4. The y-axis should be the same for the two panels, but I want both x-axis to have different values . Can that be done using SGPANEL?

Best regards,

Shaifali

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [UNISCALE](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=n0wqazuv6959fnn1fask7mi68lla.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p1wsegbk0v9jbzn18c659jj65hsn) option on your PANELBY statement to specify which axis you want fixed, the col, row or both. The default is both, which is not what you want, so specify that only the cols are fixed.

```
panelby  yourSpecifications  / uniscale = cols;
```